# How to handle conditional file downloads in meteor.js

Tags: node.js, meteor

In php you can use headers to force downloads of files, and also to hide actual file locations etc.

This is useful if you only want certain users under certain conditions to be able to download certain files.

How would I do this in meteor? I've played around with the Node.js fs module, and managed to retrieve a binary version of the file on the client. But how would I turn this to an actual file that's downloaded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three easy steps:

1. use [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite)
2. add the [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router) package: `mrt add iron-router`
3. create a server method to serve your file. Here is how an exemple:

   ```
   Router.map(function () {
     this.route('get-image', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '/img',
        action: function () {
           console.log('retrieving ' + this.request.query.name);
           this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'image/png'}, this.request.query.name);
           this.response.end(fs.readFileSync(uploadPath + this.request.query.name));
       }
     });
   });
   ```

In this example the request is a `HTTP GET` with one parameter `name=name-of-pdf.pdf`.

That's really all. Hope it was what you were looking for.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow (it's 00:25 here), makes total sense though! Did not know you could use the router this way. Thank you!

Comment: Just edited the answer to use iron-router but I don't know why the code does not appear as code. If someone could edit it and explain that would be very helpful

Comment: how exactly does this achieve the conditional part? It seems everyone with the link, or who can guess it can download it

Comment: it is very easy to check if the user is logged in or not: Meteor.userId() provides this information. Or you could add a second parameter with a token that you generated beforehand. This would allow for one time downloads. Anyhow, the example is a starting point. You still have to do some thinking